# PHP: Sort an array (woocommerce items) by item meta (array within the array)

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to sort the array of items returned from the second foreach loop of order items by a meta contained within each item (each $custom_item is it's own array). I am currently using the following code:

```
// Order variables
$user_id_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
) ) );

if ( $user_id_orders ) {
    foreach ( $user_id_orders as $user_id_order ) {
        // Foreach order variables
        $order = wc_get_order( $user_id_order );
        $order->populate( $user_id_order );
        $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
        $order_ID = $order->get_order_number();

        $custom_order = wc_get_order( $order_ID );
        $co = $custom_order->get_items();
        $co = array();

        foreach( $custom_order->get_items() as $custom_item_id => $custom_item ) {
                            $co[$custom_item_id] = $custom_item['item_meta']['Date'];
                            arsort($co);
                            print_r($co);
                            echo '<br>';
        }

        array_multisort($co, SORT_ASC, $custom_order->get_items());
    }
}
```

This code returns the following result:

```
Array ( [57] => Array ( [0] => 20/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [56] => Array ( [0] => 21/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [55] => Array ( [0] => 21/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [54] => Array ( [0] => 03/04/2011 ) ) 
Array ( [53] => Array ( [0] => 22/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [52] => Array ( [0] => 22/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [51] => Array ( [0] => 22/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [50] => Array ( [0] => 20/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [49] => Array ( [0] => 23/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [48] => Array ( [0] => 23/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [46] => Array ( [0] => 23/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [45] => Array ( [0] => 22/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [43] => Array ( [0] => 20/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [42] => Array ( [0] => 20/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [41] => Array ( [0] => 21/06/2016 ) ) 
Array ( [40] => Array ( [0] => 21/06/2016 ) )
```

Each Array is a custom item returned by the loop, and I want to order them by the retrieved dates.

So far asort inside or outside the loop hasn't worked, nor has array_multisort.

I can provide more information upon request if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `usort` which will allow you to define your own sort function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and see how I fare

Comment: usort did work, though it took a long time to get my head around. The examples aren't particularly easy to deconstruct for a person relatively new to PHP.

Thanks though!